# Is there a way/tool to check memory leak of Cocoa Touch project?

Tags: iphone

Is there a way/tool to check memory leak of Cocoa Touch project?
or
I need to write the codes by myself.

Thanks

interdev

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144261/memory-leak-detection-tools-in-xcode and possibly this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494327/how-do-you-detect-memory-leaks-on-iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XCode, Run -> Run with Performance Tool -> Leaks.

Answer (score 3):

[Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Try running "top" in the terminal while your application is running and look for a memory allocation blowing up?

Comment: Agree with Martin and Kenny now -- I just learned something new, thanks!