# which tools are used for solving memory leaks in iphone?

Tags: iphone

which tools are used for solving memory leaks in iphone ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you detect memory leaks on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494327/how-do-you-detect-memory-leaks-on-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

Plain and simple: Instruments, it's part of the Xcode suite. You can access it directly from Xcode by selecting "Run"->"Run with performance tools"->"Leaks".

Answer (score 1):

If you mean detecting then you can choose to "Run with performance tools" --> "Leaks" for checking at run times. At compile times, you can choose "Build and Analyze" to analyze your code with static Clang analyzer